# Speed up Eclipse ADT start up

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, adt, eclipse-adt

Every time I start eclipse, it takes around 15 minutes to load data from 2.3 to 5 android versions.
How can I make it faster? Do I have to un install all older android SDK or there is another way?

Comment: I suggest try to use the Android studio. it is specific for android.

Comment: I think the best way to speed up Eclipse ADT start up is by downloading Android Studio! Let me know how that goes!

Comment: Consider using Android Studio. Eclipse doesn't get new Android updates anymore.

Comment: Ok, Android studio, and if I would continue to use ADT?

Comment: If you want to keep using Eclipse...close any unwanted projects (build automatically will start building them ), i have number of Android SDKs in my workspace...haven't faced a problem like this..

Comment: if you stuck with eclipse, you can try couple of things: 1- select same API for most of project (as much as possible) 2- close unused projects so   eclipse will not load the API related to that project -if it was only for that project-